# Passing data into SUMPRODUCT

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, range, sumproduct

I previously used the following code -

```
Dim HSArr(2 To 250) As Variant
Dim HSVal As Long

For HSVal = LBound(HSArr) To UBound(HSArr)
HSArr(HSVal) = Cells(HSVal, 1) & " " & Cells(HSVal, 2)
Next HSVal
```

It was an array that would concatenate column A and B, then the array would be output onto the worksheet in "P2:P250".

```
Sub SumData()
    Const dFormula As String _
        = "=IFERROR(SUMPRODUCT(--(P$2:P$250=I2),D$2:D$250,F$2:F$250),"""")"
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("K2:K250")
        .Formula = dFormula
        .Value = .Value
    End With
End Sub
```

This code does what I want to an extent but requires "P2:P250" to contain the array output, but I don't want to output anything onto the worksheet.

There's a piece of information that I do not understand here, how I can introduce those values from the array into the SUMPRODUCT (instead of "P2:P250"), even if its not by methods of array, as AFAIK I can't use that as a range without it being on the worksheet itself. Any idea?

Comment: If you are building the array in the 1st batch of code.  Look at putting the information you require in a dictionary, where you'd have the information from `Cells(HSVal, 1) & " " & Cells(HSVal, 2)` as the key and then the info required in the item.  SumData will then be redundant as is and can be replaced by a function, like `GetFromCol(strKey as string)` or passing an excel range returning the value.  You could also use a helper column in the source of the array and just use that in your formula so P$2:P$250 would be your helper column where the array's data is coming from.

Answer (score 0):

Building an array with VBA then trying to use it with a formula in a worksheet without placing that information into a worksheet generally wouldn't work, however here you can use the source data in the formula instead:

```
=IFERROR(SUMPRODUCT(--(A$2:A$250&" "&B$2:B$250=I2),D$2:D$250,F$2:F$250),"""")
```